# Apache is serving only one page - Ubuntu 20.04 - Apache 2.4.41

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, ubuntu-20.04, virtual-host

I have installed Apache2 on my Ubuntu 20.04 server and created virtual hosts for 2 of my different websites.

The idea is to serve one content for **dog.com** and a different content for **cat.co.uk**

I have created separate directories under /var/www, gave ownerships and permissions accordingly and in a way both web-sites work.

If I turn off one of the virtual hosts with

```
sudo a2dissite dog.com.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

and go to either **dog.com** or **cat.co.uk** then the contents of **cat.co.uk** are served for both addresses.

If I enable the **dog.com.conf** but disable another one like so:

```
sudo a2ensite dog.com.conf
sudo a2dissite cat.co.uk.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

And I go to **dog.com** or **cat.co.uk** then the contents of **dog.com** are showed for both addresses.

If I enable both :

```
sudo a2ensite dog.com.conf
sudo a2ensite cat.co.uk.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

And go to either **dog.com** or **cat.co.uk** on both occasions the contents of **cat.co.uk**  are showed.
And ideally it should be different contents for different addresses.

Here is the output of some of commands that should create an overview of my situation

```
tomas@ubuntu:~$ apache2ctl -S 
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.cat.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cat.co.uk.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.cat.co.uk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cat.co.uk.conf:1)
                 alias cat.co.uk
         port 80 namevhost www.dog.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dog.com.conf:1)
                 alias dog.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used`
```

Contents of **cat.co.uk.conf** :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tomas@gmail.com
    ServerName www.cat.co.uk
    ServerAlias cat.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cat.co.uk
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Contents of **dog.com.conf** :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin tomas@gmail.com
    ServerName www.dog.com
    ServerAlias dog.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dog.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When running `apache2ctl -S` I was getting `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server’s fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the ‘ServerName’ directive globally to suppress this message`

So I added `ServerName localhost` at the end of **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** and the error disappeared

My **/etc/hosts** file contents :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

127.0.1.1       ubuntu

164.133.173.127                 dog.com
164.133.173.127                 cat.co.uk
```

My ip

```
tomas@ubuntu:~$ ip addr show eno0
2: eno0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:4d:7b:48:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 164.133.173.127/24 brd 164.132.173.255 scope global dynamic eno0
       valid_lft 79549sec preferred_lft 79549sec
    inet6 2001:41d0:1008:2181::1/56 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::222:4dff:fe7b:48bd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

dns

```
tomas@ubuntu:~$ host dog.com
dog.com has address 184.169.131.242
tomas@ubuntu:~$ host cat.co.uk
cat.co.uk has address 184.169.131.242
```

How do I resolve this issue ?